# Как получить значение свойства у переданного в функцию объекта C#?

Tags: c#

```
    public String In_Box_Check(object Object_Name) // Проверка поля на наличие в них данных
    {
        string Status = "Incorrect";
        if (Object_Name.Text != "")
        {
            Status = "Correct";
        }
        return Status;
    }
```

Не выполняется строчка с `if`. Пишет, что у Объекта нет свойства `text`. Пробовал поставить `Value` - тот же результат. Что делать?

Comment: В качестве типа `Object_Name` указывать его реальный тип (у которого, в частности, есть свойство `Text`). А у `System.Object` действительно нет такого свойства - VS вам не врёт.

Comment: Я передаю в эту функцию текстбокс: In_Box_Check(Chanel_CBox)

Comment: Так вот в параметрах метода и указывайте, что `Object_Name` - это `TextBox`, а не просто какой-то абстрактный `object`.

Comment: Как? Я просто пока не очень шарю

Comment: `public String In_Box_Check(TextBox Object_Name)`.

Comment: Такс, а если у меня в эту функцию посылаются не только текстбоксы, но еще и комбобоксы?

Comment: Дело в том, что я привык работать в Unity3D, где я просто посылаю объект, а дальше смотрю его свойства. Тут, почему-то, есть тип данных object, однако он неуниверсален

Comment: Тогда, вероятно, подойдёт тип `Control` - родительский для всех компонентов. Кстати, это WinForms или WPF? Добавьте тег.

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov тогда `Control ObjectName`. По крайней мере, к `.Text` у вас тогда доступ будет.

Comment: Сейчас протестируем

Comment: Разве WinForm отличается от WPF?

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо, Александр!

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov _Разве WinForm отличается от WPF?_ - целиком и полностью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для понимания.

> Пишет, что у Объекта нет свойства text.
>
> Тут, почему-то, есть тип данных object, однако он неуниверсален

Все классы в языке c# наследуются от класса `System.Object` (можно писать просто `object`). В нём определены буквально два-три метода -- и они есть у всех потомков этого класса (читай -- у всех классов в вашем проекте). Это `ToString`, `Equals`, `GetType` и... ещё несколько.

Полей и свойств у данного класса нет. Совсем.

Поэтому ваша попытка обратится к какому-то свойству ожидаемо вызывает ошибку на этапе компиляции, именно на этапе обращения к свойству. Из-за того, что любой класс является потомком `System.Object` его можно привести к базовому типу и передать в какой-либо метод.

Поэтому и решение в комментариях вам предложили совершенно естественное и логичное: корректно указать имя класса, которое вы передаёте.